How to use element in select in where clause in mysql query
Ive a simple table with four colums:



id
date
prev
cam




1
2024-07-06
98955
41


2
2024-07-05
98955
31


3
2024-07-05
98000
41


4
2024-07-06
100955
41



I have to create a query to show only element prev had a different cam in day before 2024-07-06.
So the result will be only the first row.
I tried a query like this:
SELECT prev as ID,camera as CM,(
SELECT cam as MC
    FROM  maincourante 
    WHERE  cam!= 
    (
        SELECT  cam 
        FROM  maincourante 
        WHERE  prev = ID AND mc_data='2024-07-05'
    )
)  AS ctrl
FROM maincourante as mc WHERE data='2024-07-06' ;


What version of mysql are you using?

if you're using MySQL 8.x you can use the LAG() window function to get the previous row.

The version is 5.6.51

You need to use aliases for the maincourante table, otherwise you cannot distinguish between table for current row and table for previous row. I would probably go for a self join and not corralated subquery, but the same concept applies to the corralated subquery as well.
select *
from maincourante m1
inner join maincourante mm2 on m1.prev = m2.prev
where m1.date = '2024-07-06' and m2.date ='2024-07-05' and m1.cam<>m2.cam

Please note, I used the column names from the sample data table as your column names are completely inconsistent in the sample query.
